# CUDA threading allocation

Tags: cuda

I have gone through the CUDA programming guide and I cannot understand the thread allocation method shown below:

```
dim3 dimGrid( 2, 2, 1 );
dim3 dimBlock( 4, 2, 2 );
KernelFunction<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(. . .);
```

Can some explain how threads are allocated for the above condition?

Comment: read the Programming Guide. again.

Answer (score 5):

An intuitive way to think about **grid** and **block** is to visualize them:

- **Grid**: A grid is a lattice of horizontal and vertical lines. Thus it has only 2 dimensions.
- **Block**: Think of a block of wood. It has all 3 dimensions: length, width and height.
- A block is made up of threads.
- A grid is made up of blocks.

Your `dimBlock( 4, 2, 2 )` means that each block has `4 x 2 x 2 = 16` threads.
Your `dimGrid( 2, 2, 1 )` means that the grid has `2 x 2 x 1 = 4` blocks.
Thus, your kernel is launched on a grid of 4 blocks, where each block has 16 threads. To conclude, your kernel will be launched with `16 x 4 = 64` threads.

Comment: wow..this is a great way of thinking about it.  Thanks for sharing.